# WordpressのEasy Digital DownloadsでPaypalの会計ボタンを有効にしたい

Tags: wordpress, paypal

こんにちは、rerereysolと申します。
初めてご質問をさせていただきます。
とても困っているので、どなたかお知恵をいただけますと嬉しいです。

現在WordpressのEasy Digital DownloadsでPaypalの設定を
しているのですが、会計ボタンが有効になりません。
どのような原因が考えられますでしょうか？

- Paypalビジネスアカウントは作成し、全ての情報確認を済ませてあります
- 「ダウンロード設定」ページは全て入力はしてあります
- HPには以下のように「購入ボタン」は表示されます
- しかし購入ボタンを押しても会計へ進むことができません
  （購入ボタンを押すとページ最上部へ移動する挙動が見られます）

実際の画面のスクショはこちらです↓

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

正常な挙動をするために、何を行う（または確認する）必要がありますでしょうか？

恐れ入りますが、みなさまのお力添えをお願いいたします！

Answer (score 2):

WordPress関連の質問は**WordPressサポートフォーラム**という有志の方が回答してくれるフォーラムの方がアクティブなのでおすすめです。1時間以内に回答をいただけたこともありました。

サポートフォーラム — WordPress : https://ja.wordpress.org/support/

今回の情報だけだと問題が明確にわからないのですし他のプラグインが悪さをしている可能性があるため、まずは以下のことを試してみることをおすすめします。

1. Easy Digital Downloads以外のプラグインを無効化する
2. Easy Digital Downloadsだけを有効化してテストしてみる

ここまでで通常の動作がするのであれば、他のプラグイン (公式にあがっているものでなく野良プラグインなどは特に危ない) や使っているテーマ、設置しているサーバを疑うべきでしょう。

また、設定がちゃんとされていない可能性もあるので下記ソースから設定方法を確認してみるのもよいでしょう。

Easy Digital Downloads – ダウンロード販売サイトを簡単に作れるWordPressプラグイン | ネタワン : http://netaone.com/wp/easy-digital-downloads/